# UnderscoreJs: _.groupBy together with _.sortBy

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to use underscores `_.groupBy()` and `_.sortBy` in pair, and a problem is that the last one changes object with keys returned from `groupBy` to array with indexes. Is it possible to preserve original indexes (keys) from object?

Here is example:

My code:

```
var sorted = _.chain(cars).groupBy('Make').sortBy(function(car) {
    return car.length * -1;
});
```

Result from `groupBy`:

```
{ 
    "Volvo" : [ "S60", "V40" ],
    "Volkswagen" : [ "Polo", "Golf", "Passat" ]
}
```

Result from `sortBy`:

```
[ 
    0 : [ "Polo", "Golf", "Passat" ],
    1 : [ "S60", "V40" ]
]
```

Expected result:

```
[
    "Volkswagen" : [ "Polo", "Golf", "Passat" ],
    "Volvo" : [ "S60", "V40" ]
]
```

Comment: Are you planning to show your `cars` variable?

Comment: You cannot sort objects (keys have no order), you can only sort arrays! Your "expected result" is a syntax error.

Comment: @Bergi Yes I know that this is not possible, but still you can have such an array: `var arr = []; arr["Volvo"] = ["S60", "V40"]`. That is the one I was referring.

Comment: @AndriyHoren: [The horror](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/). Those are still not ordered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects are unordered in JavaScript. If you need something like an object but ordered, you can use `_.pairs` to convert it, then sort the list of pairs.

```
_.pairs({ 
    "Volvo" : [ "S60", "V40" ],
    "Volkswagen" : [ "Polo", "Golf", "Passat" ]
})
```

Gives:

```
[
    ["Volvo", [ "S60", "V40" ]],
    ["Volkswagen", [ "Polo", "Golf", "Passat" ]]
]
```

...which you can then sort using `_.sortBy`. If you assign the above to `cars`, then:

```
_.sortBy(cars, function(x) { return -x[0].length; });
```

gives:

```
[
    [ 'Volkswagen', ['Polo', 'Golf', 'Passat' ]],
    [ 'Volvo', ['S60', 'V40']]
]
```